# WF4: Bookmark with NonBlocking option

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Has anyone used CreateBookmark() with BookmarkOptions.NonBlocking?
I'm trying to use it with MultipleResume option but seems I cannot even resume.

### Bookmark activity:

```
    public InArgument<string> BookmarkName { get; set; }
    public InArgument<BookmarkOptions> BookmarkOptions { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var options = BookmarkOptions.Get(context);
        context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context),
                                          ReadCompleteCallback,options);
    }
```

---

Test Code:

---

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        InitWorkflow();
        wfat = WorkflowApplicationTest.Create(sm);
        wfat.TestActivity();
        Assert.IsTrue(wfat.WaitForIdleEvent());
        var res = wfat.TestWorkflowApplication.ResumeBookmark("First", "data");
        Assert.IsTrue(res == BookmarkResumptionResult.Success, "Resumption fail with result:" + res);
        Assert.IsTrue(wfat.Bookmarks.Contains("First"), "No first bkmk");

    }


    private void InitWorkflow()
    {

        sm = new StateMachine()
        {
            States = 
             {        //First state with non blocking bookmark             
                 new State(){
                      DisplayName = "First",Entry = new BookmarkActivity(){BookmarkName = "First",BookmarkOptions =
                                BookmarkOptions.NonBlocking | BookmarkOptions.MultipleResume},
                      Transitions = 
                      {
                            new Transition(){ }
                     }
                 },    //Second state with blocking bookmark
                 new State(){
                     DisplayName = "Second",Entry =  new BookmarkActivity(){BookmarkName = "Second",BookmarkOptions =
                                BookmarkOptions.None},
                     Transitions = 
                     {
                         new Transition(){ }
                     }
                 },
                 new State(){
                     DisplayName = "End",
                    IsFinal = true
                 }
             }
        };
        sm.InitialState = sm.States[0];
        sm.InitialState.Transitions[0].To = sm.States[1];
        sm.States[1].Transitions[0].To = sm.States[2];
    }
```

---

Result of ResumeBookmark in above test code is 'NotFound'

I would appreciate any working code that demonstrates NonBlocking option.

Comment: Did you manage to persist and resume a nonblocking bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even ***NonBlocking*** bookmarks are removed when the activity that created it is completed. They allow the activity to continue execution but that's it.

Bottom line you've to maintain an activity in a not completed state (usually the outside activity) and everything inside it will execute even when a ***NonBlocking*** bookmark is found.

That's why you're getting a *NotFound* error. The activity that created the bookmark has ended and the bookmark no longer exists.

P.S.: A somehow usual use case for *NonBlocing* bookmarks is, for example, when you've a long running activity, that might throw exceptions while executing, and that way you've the possibility to resume the workflow at a previous state.

Comment: thanks for the correct answer. Could you elaborate little bit more about the use case you mentioned? I still cannot picturize that use case.